# how to make cicular border corners (not rounding corners)

Tags: html, css

how do change border corners style on a font?

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 3px blue;
```

this sets the border, it's applied on font's contour.

As you can see in my case I have very sharp thingy on the contour and I would prefer a bit more orthogonal style. As the line would end like on my sketch with red pencil. Or if someone doesn't like this style, can they change to round stroke?

[image]

Comment: Is that an SVG? Or a HTML element? It's really unclear what you're trying to show us.

Comment: @Terry Sorry, I added some more information. It's a font that I need the border having so. https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/285892.image0.jpg exactly that what you can set in illustrator under corner, the third option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. You could do it on a `<canvas>`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;

function paint() {
  canvas.width = 500 * dpr;
  canvas.height = 120 * dpr;

  ctx.lineJoin = "bevel";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3 * dpr;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx.font = (140 * dpr) + "px serif";

  ctx.strokeText("Hello!", 20 * dpr, 110 * dpr);
}
paint();

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  if (dpr !== window.devicePixelRatio) {
    dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
    paint();
  }
});
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

This is what it looks like when you zoom in:

[image]